# Should I store image paths in one table, or multiple tables based on image type?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I'm making a shopping website and need to store paths for these types of images:

- User Avatars x 250,000
- Product Images x 10,000,000
- Customer Photos x 100,000
- Forum Uploads x 50,000

Where the number of images in each category is constantly growing.

Would it be better for me to create a separate table for each type of image, or to put them all into a single table with a `type` column to distinguish between them?

The reason I'm thinking it might be better to put them into separate tables is that the number of product images, for example, will always be significantly higher than the number of user images. So when a user changes their avatar, or when a page is loaded where avatars are retrieved from the database, then wouldn't it save a lot of time adding/retrieving the record if the tables were separate?

Comment: This is not just about efficiency. It is about keeping related information together. (1) each product will have a description that will likely include an image but not always.  Each 'user' may have an 'avatar' as an image but not always. Note, entities have attributes that may be stored as images. Please do not confuse the represention (images) with the attributes. How you store them is up to you. How the information is stored may be important, so you may need to store how it is stored with the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. If it is just an URI you could store it in the table where the actual data belongs. So for the user's avatar, use a field in the `user` table.

If you have more properties for the image and fields are shared amongst image types, there is no harm in saving them in the same `image` table.

Another thing to keep in mind is the frequency of changing the field values. If for some type rows are frequently changed or deleted / added, it might be better performance wise to group volatile data together.

Comment: `If for some type rows are frequently changed or deleted / added, it might be better performance wise to group volatile data together.` Could you expand on this a little? I'm not sure what you mean. Regarding the frequency of changing values: product images will constantly be being added, but will not change often. Same goes for customer photos and user uploads. Really the only type that will change frequently is avatars.

Comment: To give an example elaborating on the last paragraph in my question, if a user uploads an avatar and it's in the same table as products, then the whole index would need to be recalculated, right? If in separate tables, just the much smaller avatars index would have to be recalculated..

Comment: Recalculating indexes is one of the reasons it might be wise to break up volatile and non-volatile content. Also the content themselves is saved in blocks, and you don't want holes in it. You have to do extra maintenance on it to compress it again.

Comment: I agree with Patrick that you shouldn't have a separate table for avatars, but he didn't mean that you should mix it with the image table. You should keep it in the table where the rest of the entity is housed.

Comment: For example, avatars in user table, product images in product table, forum uploads in the individual post. The only table that might contain image only is for customer photos. If that customer photo relates to a product, have that as relationship table to the review.